# Joda DateTime no se compila

Tags: java, maven, jodatime

El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

Cuando compilo mi código no tengo ningún error pero al ejecutarlo me salta el error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
```

Tengo la api de Joda implementada por Maven en mi `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

La línea en la que me da el error es la siguiente:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Igualmente no creo que sea por la línea porque este error me salta en cualquier línea que intento utilizar esta clase.

He decompilado mi programa y he visto que no está la clase `org.joda` compilada.

pom.xml completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.zargum.hub</groupId>
    <artifactId>zHub</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>.</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactSet>
                        <includes>
                            <include>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver</include>
                        </includes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-v${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy file="target/${project.artifactId}-v${project.version}.jar"
                                      tofile="C:\Users\negat\OneDrive\Escritorio\${project.artifactId}.jar"/>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigot-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.lucko.luckperms</groupId>
            <artifactId>luckperms-api</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Las dependencias no se compilan. Si tu proyecto no la tiene incluida es porque algo estas haciendo mal al empaquetar las dependencias.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero hasta ahí sé. Mi entorno de desarrollo (IntelliJ) si detecta la dependencia y importa las clases perfectamente pero es a la hora de compilar cuando tengo el problema. En mi pom.xml aparece la dependencia cargada, es decir no me da ningun error en el código, pero a la hora de compilar es como si omitiese esa dependencia.

Comment: ¿Como compilas exactamente? ¿Tiene algún scope la dependencia?

Comment: Utilizo el comando de maven "mvn clean install" y no, no tiene ningún scope la dependencia.

Comment: Por algún motivo Maven no la incluye en el resultado final: ¿estás generando un WAR, un EAR, un JAR...?

Comment: Estoy compilandolo en un .jar

Comment: ¿Puedes ponernos el pom.xml para ver si hay algo raro?

Comment: Ya está, ahí lo puse.

Comment: @JDev entonces??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Por fin lo he conseguido!

Lo he solucionado utilizando el plugin de maven "maven-shade-plugin".
Aquí os dejo la solución:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId> //<----
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <artifactSet>
            <includes>
                <include>org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver</include>
                <include>joda-time:joda-time</include>
            </includes>
        </artifactSet>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-v${project.version}</finalName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Yo ya utilizaba este plugin, solo he añadido la línea marcada con una flecha y ya. Cualquier duda preguntadme.
Muchas gracias a todos los que comentaron y espero que os ayude.